# How to tabedit a remote file in vim

Tags: vim, terminal

I have two files A and B.  A is on my local machine and B is on a remote machine.  I want to certain text from A to certain locations in B.  I'm using vim.  What is the best way to do this?

If both files were local, I would just do

```
vim A
:tabedit B
```

then I'd be able to easily switch between the two.  Is there anything similar for remote files?

Comment: If a file is accessible through network, I don't see why tabedit wouldn't work.

Comment: Suppose my remote computer is remote.desktop.com what would I write? `:tabedit remote.desktop.com:/B`?

Comment: Navigate to the appropriate folder on remote computer through file manager, right click and choose "open in terminal" (this is what I can to in Linux Mint). This will open terminal with path to that folder and you can use it. This is how I do such things, I'm not sure if there's a better way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is included with netrw. Take a look at `:h netrw` and `:h netrw-read`. So you could just type the following to edit thats on the remote server.

```
tabedit scp://[user@]machine[[:#]port]/path
```

(A copy of the file is pulled to the local machine and then when you save it is uploaded to the remote)